# Inject client MAC into HTTP header on Cisco router

Tags: cisco, http

I am researching for a project specification and I would like to know if it is possible to get the MAC address of a client machine connected to a Cisco router and then inject that address into any HTTP traffic that the controller sends to a proxy.

The basic overview of the architecture and what I want is client connects to router, router connects to controller and controller connects to proxy. I want the controller to basically know which client MAC addresses are connected to the router and what they are viewing.

Comment: Normally product recommendation and similar Questions are completely Off Topic on all [SE] sites. But, the answer is "no", so it doesn't matter. On a side note, if you're looking to do some kind of employee monitoring might I strongly suggest not trying install e-babysitters and simply evaluating employee retention based on production (ie, if they aren't getting their work done, replace them with someone who appreciates having a job). If this is for public/regulated access, quite a few companies make packaged solutions for schools, libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in Cisco routers that can do this. In fact, I doubt any router has such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a partial yes, but I say so with the assumption you're trying to track on a granular level a NAT'd host accessing web content?

And can I assume you're in an administrative function of the network hosting the clients and the proxy server ?  But your clients might be remotely spread and on networks you don't necessarily control such as home based and franchise offices ?  Like remote employees accessing your network over a VPN and using your internet gateway?

Are those assumptions correct, or any of the  partially correct ?

Comment: Yes to the first question. I am in the administrative function of hosting the proxy and the controller to the routers that the client connects to. The clients are not remotely spread, they are local to the vicinity of the network and we control the networks that they are on. Think of people accessing a wifi-hotspot inside of a Chick-Fil-A.